# PCB Board design for H-Bridge TLE5206

Tags: pcb-design, thermal, heat-protection

I would like to make PCB board for TLE 5206-2G (check the [datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/tle5206-2_1.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b438231a6a4f&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b43823a06a50)).
It is TO263 package.

Basically, what i dont know is how to transfer heat out of the IC. I saw few PCB's that has little copper square with grid of holes in it. Is that what is used for taking out the heat?

Datasheet (page 21) says: *Metal surface min. X=7.25, Y=6.9*. Is that refers to heat transfer surface ? Will plated holes enhanced heat transfer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sorts of devices (surface mount with exposed metal) are meant to be directly coupled to heavy copper on the PCB to get the heat out of the device.

Usually this involves a multilayer PCB, with a bunch of vias that connect copper on several layers to the device metal. The vias not only channel heat through the PCB by conduction, they also ensure that the device is well soldered with good copper-to-copper contact.